# Why does my website link not show previews?

Tags: html, css

So I own a website and previews will not show on various places where I put the URL. I was told to put a favicon on the site, and I did, but that doesn't work.

I've tried using different variations of code, those don't seem to work either.

Here's the head section on the index page:

```
<head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-142179954-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-142179954-1');
    </script>

    <title>Dieselworks</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/files/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

Just want this site to show previews wherever it is linked.

Comment: Perhaps you want `meta tags`? https://www.heymeta.com/

Comment: Did you try to open the page in Incognito tab? Do you see any errors in the Network tab in the developer tools?

Comment: please put the favicon at root directory and clean your cache. it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the late response, kinda just forgot about this post. I did solve it however, here's what I did:

```html
<title>text</title> --title that goes on the tab and the preview
<meta name="description" content="text"> --description for the preview
<meta property="og:image" content="imageurl" /> --image to put on the preview
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your favicon *syntax* looks fine. Most of the site favicons I support are in PNG format and they don't have to live in some special favicon directory. Any web dir will do.

The favicon or site icon will show up in the browser tab and browser popular sites tabs on mobile. You'll need a retina version (2x) if you notice your favicon is pixelated on mobile displays.

Back to **previews**. I assume you mean *social media previews* like **FB** and **Twitter**. Maybe WhatsApp if you use it.

FB introduced and uses the Open Graph protocol for these previews. Read more here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

You can **view source** on any site that has preview working. Search on "og:" and you'll see their Open Graph markup that generates their preview in FB.

Here's an Open Graph markup e.g. taken from FB dev page.

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
```

Twitter is a different beast. Get all the details for generating **Twitter Cards** for their previews. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started.html

If your site is on **WordPress**, *Yoast* will take care of this for you. Just fill-in your site details in the Social Sharing tab in the Yoast plugin.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following URL to generate your favicon.

It also offers simple steps as to where you need to add the favicon in your code.

https://realfavicongenerator.net/